# Получить данные из сайта по наименованию товара

Tags: excel, vba

Я человек далекий от VBA, пытаюсь разобраться и написать макрос, который будет брать наименование товара, заходить на сайт поставщика, брать данные там и заполнять ячейки в Excel, что сильно облегчит мне жизнь, но столкнулся с проблемой, на форуме нашел макрос, помогите понять как он работает.

```
    inpdate = CDate(InputBox("Введите дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ",_ "Курс EUR", Date))
    d = Format(inpdate, "dd")
    m = Format(inpdate, "mm")
    y = Format(inpdate, "yyyy")

    sURI = "http://cbr.ru/currency_base/daily.aspx?C_month=" & m & _
                    "&C_year=" & y & "&date_req=" & d & "%2F" & m & "%2F" & y

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    If oHttp Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    oHttp.Open "GET", sURI, False
    oHttp.Send
    htmlcode = oHttp.responseText
    outstr = Mid(htmlcode, InStr(1, htmlcode, "EUR") + 81, 7)

    Set oHttp = Nothing
    outstr = Replace(outstr, ",", ".")
    ActiveCell.Value = outstr
End Sub
```

Comment: Через одно место, но в принципе вроде вполне понятно... Что именно непонятно? Кроме +81 и 7?

Comment: Не понятен именно этот момент, то есть что именно он делает и как работает.
On Error Resume Next
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
If oHttp Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub

Comment: Вы же не просто так взяли первый подвернувшийся макрос... Задача Ваша в чем состоит? Для чего нужен макрос? Это и должно быть в заголовке. Зашли за помощью - помогите и Вы будущим посетителям. Где начало макроса?

Comment: Нет, не просто, я начал работать копирайтерем. Из-за огромного обьема работы, мне пришла идея написать макрос , который будет брать наименование товара, заходить на сайт поставщика , брать данные там и заполнять ячейки в excel, но я этом я полный чайник. Поэтому очень много не понятных моментов, а просить некого, да и не удобно, ибо макрос нужен мне.Прошу прощения за не корректный заголовок, первый раз пишу на подобный форум

Answer (score 1):

```vb
' Отключаем обработку ошибок
' В случае ошибки ничего не валится, просто пордолжается выполнение скрипта
On Error Resume Next

' Создаём один из объектов для оправки http-запросов, а именно MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Если произошла ошибка, считаем что MSXML2.XMLHTTP не поддерживается
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  ' И создаём вместо него более MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
  Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
End If

' Возвращаем стандартную обработку ошибок
On Error GoTo 0

' Мы не проверяли, удалось ли создать MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
' Если не удалось, в oHttp будет вместо него лежать Nothing - проверям
If oHttp Is Nothing Then
  ' Ну и если действительно не получилось - закругляемся и выходим из процедуры
  Exit Sub
End If
```